# AVD option not appearing in android settings for appium

Tags: android, appium

I'm running Appium on windows,

When I open the application and open the Android settings, there is a launch device setting which I want to point to an AVD I have set running from AVD manager.

However in this dropdown list the only options are my unrelated development VM's and there is no way to enter a path direct to my desired AVD.

How do you get Appium to be able to find your AVDs from AVD manager?

Comment: why do you want to add avd with appium ?

Comment: Ive never used it before, im following this tutorial http://dentedghost.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/appium-android-browser-emulator-simple.html

Comment: You don't need to setup those thing, download appium and install in your window machine. To run appium you should install and setup environment variable of Android and Java. For more details follow link:http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2014/02/road-to-setup-and-create-first-appium.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a path to your AVD. Simply enter the name of the AVD you made into the AVD field.

To make Appium find your AVD, you need to set ANDROID_HOME path to the root android folder in your environment variables.

Comment: That's what I would want to do, the AVD field though isnt editable you can only select whats available in the drop down list

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Set ANDROID_HOME path to the root android folder in your environment variables. Then Appium should be able to find the AVD.